# why is input button's size different from css style?

Tags: html, css, macos

I am working on an electron app on macOS.

In the CSS file, I specified the input size to be 21px height.

CSS

```
input {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 21px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Choose a file" id="fileInput">
<br style = "clear:left">
```

But in the app, the button seems to be 18 px height.

[image]

I checked in dev tools. the element sizing looks like this.

[image]

Why is the input button size different from the height specified in the CSS file. Was it due to the "margin-bottom" properties I specified?

Update:

I tried to add the `!important` tag, did not work.

Checked CSS files, no 18px specified anywhere.

Are there any other possibilities the input button size affected/overwritten by other CSS attribute, float for example?

Update 2:

I tried the app on Windows system, the button has the right size of 21px.

The issue seems to be a macOS specified issue.

Comment: Try adding the !important tag to your height as a test. Did  it display as expected? If so, you’ve got another style overriding what you’re expecting somewhere down the line.

Comment: use line-height instead

Comment: It should work, try using the id name in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it is getting overridden by any other height which is specified to 18px .  and as people are suggesting use of "!important" try to avoid using it . Try with css selectors. to make it more specific to your input field.

Answer (score 1):

You code perfectly sets the height in all major browsers.

Maybe a CSS framework overrides the default style. Try to add the `!important` tag behind the height attribute like so: `height: 21px !important;`. **Please note**, that this is **not best practice** [explanation found here](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/).

If you need further help, please let us know whether you use a CSS framework (maybe some JS code could also override it) and which browser you're using.